# How to get UK date format in ruby?

Tags: ruby, date

Can anyone tell me how to set the UK date format in ruby?  Value should be get in terminal.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the `strftime` method

> Formats time according to the directives in the given format string.
>
> The directives begin with a percent (%) character. Any text not listed as a directive will be passed through to the output string.
>
> The directive consists of a percent (%) character, zero or more flags, optional minimum field width, optional modifier and a conversion specifier as follows:

```
Time.now.strftime("%d/%m/%y")

=> "29/09/15"
```

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Time.html#method-i-strftime

Comment: If I'm using UK format for date of birth. How to use in the below line.. Print "Enter you dob:" dob =gets

Comment: How to use strftime method with get method. If I'm getting value in console..like. date_of_birth = gets on that how to check whether the given date is in UK format? Or not

Answer (score 1):

Try this in `irb`:

```
t = Time.now
 => 2015-09-29 16:39:52 +0100 
t.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
 => "29/09/2015"
```